# Do I need to use the 'add' function in mips to store into a variable or can I store into a variable with load word?

Tags: assembly, mips, code

The following problems deal with translating from C to MIPS. Assume that the variables f,g,h,i, and j are assigned to registers $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3, and $s4, respectively. Assume that the base address of the arrays A and B are registers $s6 and $s7, respectively. Write the MIPS code for the following C lines of code:
**I am trying to mimic the following code snippet from a C program and write it in MIPS.**

```
if(g != h){
      f = A[3];
   } else{
      f = B[4];
   }
```

**Below is the MIPS I have so far**

```
bne $s1, $s2, Tru        
lw  $s0, 16($s7)         
j Done                   
Tru: lw  $t0, 12($s6)   
     add $s0, $t0, $zero
Done:
```

If I was unclear please comment below.

Answer (score 1):

You used `lw $s0, 16($s7)` for your `f=B[4];` line.

As long as that line works, why are you overcomplicating `f=A[3];` with the additional ASM line `add $s0, $t0, $zero`?
Just `lw $s0, 12($s6)` & be done with it.

Comment: ok so as long as you lw into the $s0 register, your fine?

Comment: @BrandonWoodard If you were to assume that you could _not_ lw into the $s0 register directly, how would using lw into $t0; then adding $t0+$zero into $s0 circumvent anything? - To my knowlege, there's no intance where you could gain anything (besides increased CPU lag) by adding the second operation there. .. So yes, as long as you lw the correct value into $s0, that sets f=__ correctly.